# Multiple fields not display in single form and model Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model product. I want to create multiple record in single model (product), but fields not display in view

```
#controller

@products = Array.new(3){ Product.new }

# view

<%= form_tag create_product_path, :method => :post, :class => "form-horizontal",  'role' => "form" do %>
<% @products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
 <% fields_for "products[#{index}]", product do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :date  %>
   <%= f.text_field :name  %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= submit_tag "Submit", :class => "btn btn-primer" %>
```

Look at this screenshoot, fields not appear. Can anyone tell me, why new form method using array not appear?

[image: notdisplay]

Comment: Did you try using just `@products = Product.new` ?

Comment: yes, I did.. and form displayed.

Comment: worked if single record. but not worked if multiple record use `@products = Array.new(3){ Product.new }`

Comment: Try `@products = Product.new(3)`

Comment: I get an error : `undefined method 'stringify_keys' for 3:Fixnum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget about `<%=` on `fields_for`

read about [fields_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for)

rails 2.x - 3.0

```
<% fields_for "products[#{index}]", product do |f| %>
```

rails > 3.1.x

```
<%= fields_for "products[#{index}]", product do |f| %>
```